# Add border to part of the content of a tinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce

I would like to have the same option as word to put a border around a selected part of the editor's content.

Is there such option? or any plugin doing it ? 
Google search returns nothing for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as I couldn't find the feature, I actually made my own plugin, here it is :

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('borderinsert', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('border_insert', {
        text: 'Border',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            var text_selected = editor.selection.getContent();
            var text_modified = "<span style='border: 1px solid black; padding: 1pt 2pt;'>"+text_selected+"</span>";
            editor.selection.setContent(text_modified);
        }
    });
});
```

Create a new folder in your tinymce plugin directory and call it `borderinsert`
Create a new file called plugin.min.js, paste the code in it, then just add the plugin name in your tinymce init as follow :

```
tinymce.init({
   ...
   your options
   ...
   plugins: [... your plugins ... , borderinsert],
   toolbar1: "border_insert"
```